# C++ crossplatform reflection libraries - compilable, tested with samples are there any?

Tags: c++, reflection, boost, cross-platform

So I for example love Boost and all related to it so I found for my self some [Boost.Extension](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/) and [Boost.Reflection](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/reflection/) with [one sample on how to use them](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/libs/reflection/examples/extension/). Which I [can compile inside under VS2008 but it fails during execution (you can try for your self here)](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-HzAcJborshM2Q2ZjllZjMtYzc2Ny00MzhhLWJlZTMtZTYzZjVhZDEwYmE3&sort=name&layout=list&num=50) and which does not compile under linux for me at all. ([I tried to convert all Boost.Extension samples to be compilable from my favorite IDEs](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/wiki/BoostExtensionTutorialsWithPremake) via [Premake](http://industriousone.com/what-premake))... So all in all Boost candidates seemed to me like best shot - I use Boost all the time... but I cant compile one so much needed sample... So I ask you - community

- How to make boost sample work?
- Are there cross-platform alternatives to this pare for Extension-Reflection (that you have tested)?

***Update:*** [Just made project compilable under linux (modified Boost.Extension a bit)](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/?r=1106#svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial)

Comment: Have you looked at [boost.mirror](http://kifri.fri.uniza.sk/~chochlik/mirror-lib/html/)?

Comment: @ildjarn: no, but I will give it try if you recommend.

Comment: @ildjarn:  But Isnt it declared to be tested only with GCC compiler?

Comment: well, at least GCC works on a lot of platforms.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Mayby try http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetaobject.html